# Permission to display edit profile link

Tags: users

I'm customizing user profile page in my Drupal 7 site. I decided to remove menu tabs on the page by modifing template.php file with following code
    `function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
    unset($variables['tabs']);
    }`
Insted of tabs I created block in `user-profile.tpl.php` and moved links from tabs there
    `

```
        <?php print l(t('Edit profile'), "user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}/edit"); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="user-profile-subscriptions">
        <?php print l(t('Subscriptions'), "user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}/subscriptions");?>
    </div>
</div>`
```

How can I configure permissions to display this block only whe user is viewing own profile and hide whe viewing profile of other user?

UPD: I assume this may be possible through comparing current user name `user->name` and user name from URL but I do not know how to extract user name from URL.

Comment: You can use `user_access('administer users')`. It returns `TRUE` if user have permission to edit profiles and `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: In my case only administrator has `Administer users` permission. So it does not work for users with different roles

Comment: Then you can define your own permission and alter the menu callback

Comment: Get the user id using `arg(1)` (for any path in the form user/%).